# Add indexing in sqlite fmdb

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I am using fmdb in iOS application.I have 10000 records in my application so fmdb query is slow, for query execution speed up need to add indexing in query.Is it possible in fmdb please help me and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found to add indexing using FMDB. Its same as sql.